Most secure way to create an EOA with ethers.js
Ethers.js offers the possibility to easily create new EOAs and I have two questions on that topic:

Is there a difference in terms of security while creating a fresh mnemonic from Mnemonic.fromEntropy or Mnemonic.fromPhrase?
What exactly is password in the functions arguments list? Does this add extra security/randomness or what is the exact usage?



Mnemonic.fromEntropy creates a mnemonic from a random source and is secure if that source is truly random. Mnemonic.fromPhrase uses an existing phrase to recreate a mnemonic and is secure if the phrase is reliable. Both methods are secure if the entropy or the phrase is good.

The password adds extra protection. Even if someone has the mnemonic, they also need the password to access the wallet. Basically, it makes the wallet much harder to hack.


